# Decode this type of string in python

Tags: python, string, utf-8, imap, decode

=?UTF-8?B?TmV3IFBlcnNvbmFsIE1lc3NhZ2U6IE1vbmcgYW5oIHTDrG0gbOG6oWkgY2h1eWVudGIub3JnIQ==?=

Hi, I have this string which is what returned from an IMAP command - do anyone know how to decode this in python so I'll have the proper UTF-8 string?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> print unicode(base64.decodestring('TmV3IFBlcnNvbmFsIE1lc3NhZ2U6IE1vbmcgYW5oIHTDrG0gbOG6oWkgY2h1eWVudGIub3JnIQ=='), "utf-8")
New Personal Message: Mong anh tìm lại chuyentb.org!
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I automatically split the original string to get the two components? and use something rather than unicode() if the first parameter in the string is not 'UTF-8'?

Comment: for example: =?ISO-8859-1?B?UmU6IENo4G8gYuFj?=

Comment: `print unicode(base64.decodestring('UmU6IENo4G8gYuFj'), "8859")`

Comment: To completely answer your question, im not sure if there is a function to find the char set for you. You might just have to make a lookup table?

Comment: anyone should've made a small util / library for this right? sorry if i sound lazy, but i'm keen to find something first before writing my own.

Comment: i agree completely- I just don't know of one off the top of my head. i almost never have to deal with character sets

Comment: @Thi - I found the codec list if you have to make your own lookup table- http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: @tMC: just found out a very convenient way to do this: email.header.decode_header(s). It'll decode everything :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best way to decode this Encoded-Word is via email.header.decode_header(). It'll return you a list in which the first element is the decoded string, and the second element is the encoding.

Example:

```
email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?Q?T=e1=ba=a1p_Ch=c3=ad_Gi=e1=ba=a3m_C=c3=a2n_=28=40tapchigiamcan=29_is_now_following_you_on_Twitter=21?=')
[('T\xe1\xba\xa1p Ch\xc3\xad Gi\xe1\xba\xa3m C\xc3\xa2n (@tapchigiamcan) is now following you on Twitter!', 'utf-8')]
```